# How to set equal width on divs with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, equals

I've got five rows that looks like this:
It's an ul with lis. I want the first li "text" to be equal on all rows. To do this I need to look for the widest li, then apply the new with to all li's.

(ul > li > span & ul)

Text > Li 1 | li 2 | Li 3
Textlong > Li 1 | li 2 | Li 3
Short > Li 1 | li 2 | Li 3
Longer13456 > Li 1 | li 2 | Li 3

I've used the following function for setting equal hights. Modified it a bit. But it does not make any sense!

```
function equalWidth() {
    var span = $('#tableLookAlike li.tr > span'),
        tallest = 0, 
        thisHeight = 0;

    setEqWidth = function(elem) {
        elem.each(function() {
            widest = 0;
            thisWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
            console.log(tallest, thisWidth)



// if I remove this it gives me the right width
                elem.each(function() {Width)
                    if (thisWidth > widest) {
                        widest = thisWidth;
                        elem.css({'width': widest});
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        setEqWidth(span);
    }
```

The log shows 92, 69, 68, 118 when I remove the second elem.each, and when I put it back, it gives me 92, 130, 168, 206.
Does anyone know whats going on here?

Aynway, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function equalWidth() {
    var span = $('#tableLookAlike li.tr > span'),
        widest = 0,
        thisWidth = 0;

    setEqWidth = function(elem) {
        widest = 0;
        elem.each(function() {
            thisWidth = $(this).outerWidth();

            if (thisWidth > widest) {
                widest = thisWidth;
            }
        });

        elem.css({ 'width': widest });
    }
    setEqWidth(span);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If I was to do it, it would go something like this:

```
var greatestWidth = 0;   // Stores the greatest width

$(selector).each(function() {    // Select the elements you're comparing

    var theWidth = $(this).width();   // Grab the current width

    if( theWidth > greatestWidth) {   // If theWidth > the greatestWidth so far,
        greatestWidth = theWidth;     //    set greatestWidth to theWidth
    }
});

$(selector).width(greatestWidth);     // Update the elements you were comparing
```

Comment: What I needed was to change `$(this).width();` to > `$(this).outerWidth();` to take into account the padding and border. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

A bit more concise

```
var widest = 0;
$("#tableLookAlike li.tr > span").each(function () { widest = Math.max(widest, $(this).outerWidth()); }).width(widest);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the width of the elements at the end of your loop. Otherwise the widest value is just a temporary highest value.

```
setEqWidth = function(elem) {
    elem.each(function() {
        widest = 0;
        thisWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
        console.log(tallest, thisWidth)

        elem.each(function() {
                if (thisWidth > widest) {
                    widest = thisWidth;
                }
            });
        });


        elem.css({'width': widest});
    }
```

Comment: thanks for that, i kinda solved it like that, but there was no need to go elem.each twice..

Comment: I didn't use jQuery since a little while, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Remember: setting the width explicitly will not take into account any `padding` on the elements in question, so if those elements have `padding-left` or `padding-right` set, you're going to wind up with a width greater than your original maximum width due to padding being incorporated into width in the CSS box model.

This will even make your original element even wider than it started with. The same applies to setting height with `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`.

If you want to be super-accurate, you'll need to take `padding` into account with something like the code below (if you're not using percantages or ems or fractions of pixels to set `padding`, you can use `parseInt( )` instead of `parseFloat( )`):

```
var maxWidth = 0;
var $els = $('.your-selector');
$els.each(function(){
    var w = $(this).width();
    if(w > maxWidth){
        maxWidth = w;
    }

}

$els.each(function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    var padding = parseFloat($el.css('padding-left'),100) + parseFloat($el.css('padding-right'),100);

    $el.width(maxWidth - padding);
});
```